# Router Events failing some functionality on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I would like to show Hamberger(Menu Icon) in all pages except home page.And the code is:

```
constructor( private router: Router){
    this.router.events
       .subscribe((event) => {    
    let _url = window.location.href, urlArr: any;
    console.log(_url);
    urlArr = _url.split('/').indexOf('home');
    this._showHamburger = (urlArr < 0) ? true : false;
  });
}
```

The above code works fine if we navigate from any page to current page(It seems we must navigate from somewhere). But on page refresh the above functionality fails. Any thing I need to add up ??

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to use the [`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) service:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.url.pipe(
    map((urls) => urls.every((url) => !url.path.includes('home'))
  ).subscribe((show: boolean) => this._showHamburger = show);
}
```

Even better would be to make it without a subscribe and use the `async` pipe in your component. This takes care of any needed unsubscribes:

```
readonly showHamburger: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.showHamburger = route.url.pipe(
    map((urls) => urls.every((url) => !url.path.includes('home'))
  );
}
```

Then you can make the template like this:

```
<div *ngIf="showHamburger | async" class="hamburger">I'm a hamburger</div>
```

Comment: i get the error: 'Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'UrlSegment''. And lib inside tsconfig.json is --      "lib": [
                                     "es2017",
                                      "dom"
                                     ],

Comment: @AsridhKumar I've updated my answer, it's supposed to be `url.path.includes`

Answer (score 0):

### I think creating a new component is the best idea

The Best way you can do is create a new component and add the code of Hamberger(Menu Icon)

> Create a new Component using this

```
ng g c Hamberger
```

Use the selector like `<app-hamberger></app-hamberger>` on all the page where you want and dont add this on hope